# Cannot get data from DataSet for a specific id using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, dataset

I tried to use different examples on this site but cannot find the one that solves my problem.

I have a DataSet and I need to get all the rows from that DataSet using `Linq` with a given ID

I'm doing the following:

```
foreach (DataRow dataRow in myData.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    string id = dataRow["id"].ToString().Trim();
    var listOfData = myData.Tables[1].Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(x => x.Field<string>("id") == id);
}
```

When doing that I have an error in `Field<string>` part saying that

> DataRow does not contain definition for Field and no extension method Field accepting a first argument of DataRow...

I found another way of achieving that:

```
DataRow[] listOfData = myData.Tables[1].Select("id=" + id);
```

and it works, but I do not want to use DataRow[] and want to use Linq's query with `where` clause

What am I missing and is there another way of doing that?

Answer (score 1):

You should reference System.Data.DataSetExtensions assembly and add a using for `System.Data`. `Field<T>()` is defined as an extension function in DataRowExtensions class.

Although, seeing you are effectively doing a join in your for loop I would modify the queries used to fill up this data set in the first place and push the join to underlying DB for performance.

Comment: I need to use 2 DataSets anyway. I just need to grab all the data from a 2nd DataSet based on the ID from the 1st one

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
         foreach (DataRow dataRow in dtZeroQtyBonusReceiveRows)
            {
                string id = dataRow["id"].ToString().Trim();

                var listOfData =  zeroQuantityRows.CopyToDataTable().Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                    .Where(x => Convert.ToString(x["id"]) == id);
            }
```

Comment: @gene were you know able to get the above simple fix working?